# XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location: chrome://browser/content/places/bookmarksSidebar.xhtml Line Number 1, Column 1:

Tags: macos, firefox

I opened Firefox this morning on the most up to date version and got this instead of a bookmark tab.

My bookmarks tab is empty and it just has that error instead.

I tried restarting my browser and my computer.

Comment: Define "latest version" -Release, Development? Please [edit] and add the version number.

Comment: Check in your profile folder if the file `places.sqlite` that contains bookmarks and history isn't deleted or corrupted. Try to return it from backup.